# Iterating through this JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm new to JS, so this is a bit different than typical data structures I'm used to working with. Below is a simple snippet of code I'm trying to iterate through. I have put some sample code I have tried to at least dissect the information inside the JSON, but it's not working the way I want it to.

```
    [{
        "data": ["\t\tThe Catcher In The Rye by J. D. Salinger[Team Nanban][TPB]\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:d87b74de181abda5dc54be34713473ae025e5ea1&dn=The+Catcher+In+The+Rye+by+J.+D.+Salinger%5BTeam+Nanban%5D%5BTPB%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
        "epub_convert": 0
    }, {
        "data": ["\t\tThe Catcher In The Rye (Corrected and Updated)\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:a5db6afb1eb238fa990b02377c38088e333609ad&dn=The+Catcher+In+The+Rye+%28Corrected+and+Updated%29&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
        "epub_convert": 0
    }, {
        "data": ["\t\tTHE CATCHER IN THE RYE - J. D. Salinger.pdf\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6c146dd22323e604b74a326d23122a812a107466&dn=THE+CATCHER+IN+THE+RYE+-+J.+D.+Salinger.pdf&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
        "epub_convert": 0
    }, {
        "data": ["\t\tCatcher In The Rye (Final Proof)\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:faee3c58e847c0f2f8df00a3b5be870daa2e0dee&dn=Catcher+In+The+Rye+%28Final+Proof%29&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
        "epub_convert": 0
    }, {
        "data": ["\t\tJ.D. Salinger:The Catcher in the Rye pdf, e-pub, mobi\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:3ccfcbfbdf1d835776c4a1b02c60acf5f2dc036d&dn=J.D.+Salinger%3AThe+Catcher+in+the+Rye++pdf%2C+e-pub%2C+mobi&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
        "epub_convert": 1
    }]
```

I'm trying to iterate through this JSON, but can't seem to get the formatting correct. How would I be able to loop through getting the titles, links, and epub_convert values in a clean way?

```
#Starter Attempts
           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
             console.log(JSON.parse(data[i]));
           }

________
           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
             console.log(data[i]);
           }
_________

    console.log(data[i]['data']['epub_convert']);
```

Comment: `data.forEach(function(el, index) {
  console.log(el.epub_convert);
  el.data.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d.trim())
  })
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to iterate over array elements

```js
var data = [{
  "data": ["\t\tThe Catcher In The Rye by J. D. Salinger[Team Nanban][TPB]\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:d87b74de181abda5dc54be34713473ae025e5ea1&dn=The+Catcher+In+The+Rye+by+J.+D.+Salinger%5BTeam+Nanban%5D%5BTPB%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\t\tThe Catcher In The Rye (Corrected and Updated)\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:a5db6afb1eb238fa990b02377c38088e333609ad&dn=The+Catcher+In+The+Rye+%28Corrected+and+Updated%29&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\t\tTHE CATCHER IN THE RYE - J. D. Salinger.pdf\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6c146dd22323e604b74a326d23122a812a107466&dn=THE+CATCHER+IN+THE+RYE+-+J.+D.+Salinger.pdf&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\t\tCatcher In The Rye (Final Proof)\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:faee3c58e847c0f2f8df00a3b5be870daa2e0dee&dn=Catcher+In+The+Rye+%28Final+Proof%29&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\t\tJ.D. Salinger:The Catcher in the Rye pdf, e-pub, mobi\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:3ccfcbfbdf1d835776c4a1b02c60acf5f2dc036d&dn=J.D.+Salinger%3AThe+Catcher+in+the+Rye++pdf%2C+e-pub%2C+mobi&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 1
}];

data.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(
    v.data[0], // title
    v.data[1], // url
    v.epub_convert // epub_convert value
  );
});
```

---

In case it's a string then you need to parse it first use `JSON.parse()` method for that.

```js
var json = `[{
  "data": ["\\t\\tThe Catcher In The Rye by J. D. Salinger[Team Nanban][TPB]\\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:d87b74de181abda5dc54be34713473ae025e5ea1&dn=The+Catcher+In+The+Rye+by+J.+D.+Salinger%5BTeam+Nanban%5D%5BTPB%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\\t\\tThe Catcher In The Rye (Corrected and Updated)\\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:a5db6afb1eb238fa990b02377c38088e333609ad&dn=The+Catcher+In+The+Rye+%28Corrected+and+Updated%29&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\\t\\tTHE CATCHER IN THE RYE - J. D. Salinger.pdf\\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6c146dd22323e604b74a326d23122a812a107466&dn=THE+CATCHER+IN+THE+RYE+-+J.+D.+Salinger.pdf&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\\t\\tCatcher In The Rye (Final Proof)\\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:faee3c58e847c0f2f8df00a3b5be870daa2e0dee&dn=Catcher+In+The+Rye+%28Final+Proof%29&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 0
}, {
  "data": ["\\t\\tJ.D. Salinger:The Catcher in the Rye pdf, e-pub, mobi\\n", "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:3ccfcbfbdf1d835776c4a1b02c60acf5f2dc036d&dn=J.D.+Salinger%3AThe+Catcher+in+the+Rye++pdf%2C+e-pub%2C+mobi&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],
  "epub_convert": 1
}]`;

var data = JSON.parse(json);

data.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(
    v.data[0], // title
    v.data[1], // url
    v.epub_convert // epub_convert value
  );
});
```

---

**UPDATE :** You need to parse it like `JSON.parse(return_data.responseText)`, since the json string holds the `responseText` property.

Comment: (index):36 Uncaught TypeError: return_data.forEach is not a function, know what this could be?

Comment: Still not working, tried converting, but having errors. typeof is "object"

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this error VM3647:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @coderkid please check the value of `Array.isArray(return_data)`

Comment: It's false when I don't do JSON.parse and it errors out when I try to apply JSON.parse to it

Comment: @coderkid : can you share the data `console.log(return_data)`

Comment: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "[{"data":["\t\tThe Catcher In The Rye by J. D. Sal…F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969"],"epub_convert":1}]", responseJSON: Array[5], status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: @coderkid : you need to parse like `JSON.parse(return_data.responseText)`